# R interface to Keras: how to debug custom loss function?

Tags: r, keras, loss-function

I'm using [keras](https://keras.rstudio.com/) package in R, and would like to define a custom loss function.

While I was able to find a few examples ([one of them](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/variational_autoencoder.html)), there was nothing on how to *debug* your own loss function. That is, even if I make it work, how could I verify that it works correctly (e.g. take some `y_true` and `y_pred`, and go through the calculations)?

I tried adding a `print` statement inside the function, but nothing came out.